# Why is a' used in the proof of the front-door adjustment formula by Hernán and Robins in their book Causal inference What If

Tags: causality

Please can I confirm what the meaning of a' is in the proof of the front-door adjustment formula. I assume it represents all other treatment levels not equal to the level of interest (a) but I am unclear how it appears in the proof.

Thanks in advance

Edit 1: I have provided a picture of the proof from the book below and have underlined the speenter image description herecific line. I think I understand why the conditional exchangeability is relevant - it means we can express the counterfactual probability $Pr(Y^{m} = 1)$ via observational quantities. However, I would have written it as follows $Pr(Y^{m} = 1) = \sum_{a \in A} Pr(Y=1|M=m, A=a)Pr(A=a)$ i.e. I am unclear why a' has been used and why the notation I wrote was not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a picture of the proof or sketch it here with its notations so that it saves people from having to search for it in the book?

Comment: @periwinkle have provided an edit - thanks for the suggestion! Should have done that in the first place

Comment: This is just a question of mathematical style. Technically, the prime has no meaning at all.  Many authors might use, say, "$b$" instead of "$a^\prime.$"  The purpose evidently is twofold: (1) distinguish $a^\prime$ from $a$ and (b) suggest that $a^\prime$ is a mathematical object akin to $a.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation you used and the notation Robins used is $100\%$ equivalent. The variables $a'$ or $a$ in your formula are both dummy variables - variables used in a summation. It literally does not matter what is used, with one important caveat: a dummy variables needs to not inadvertently coincide with another variable being used, particularly in the summation. But it can help with clarity if it doesn't coincide with any variable being used anywhere else. I'm not saying, of course, that the dummy variable shouldn't show up in the summation expression: it can. But using a completely different dummy variable can have the virtue of increasing clarity by essentially saying this: "Look, I'm completely different from any variable that's defined elsewhere." Another way of saying this is that the dummy variable only has scope *in the summation* and nowhere else.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks!